# How Do Concatenate this Selector Properly?

Tags: jquery, selector

having trouble writing the selector properly:
    `document.querySelector('#idName(dynamicVariable) div')`.

The `selector` should look something like this:

`documentquerySelector( #idName23 div)` with `23` being a variable

Believe I'm messing up on the concatenation. I would think it would be something like this:

```
 `document.querySelector('#idName' + dynamicVariable 'div')`.
```

however it is not working. Sounds like a pretty easy fix but can someone show the correct way to concatenate selectors of multiple objects that may have a dynamic variable attached to them?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0ynab0y2/1/ like this?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't jQuery, but you're missing the + on the right side of the variable, and a space too:

```
document.querySelector('#idName' + dynamicVariable + ' div')
```